# Refresh Text within Swift UI after 1st run

Tags: xcode, swiftui

I am racking my brain trying to get this code working, I am just starting out on SwiftUI and haven't found a solution. I have a math equation that adds the variables and accepts the answer input from the user. My issue is once the answer is correct, how can i get the variables numbers1 & numbers2 to refresh and grab new numbers and give another math problem?

````
import SwiftUI
import Foundation


struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var answer = ""
    @State private var number1 = ""
    @State private var number2 = ""

    @State private var messageText = ""
    @State private var keyboardHeight: CGFloat = 0.0


    var numbers1 : Int = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].randomElement()!
    var numbers2 : Int = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].randomElement()!

    var questionNumber = 0
    var value = 0.00


    var body: some View {

        VStack {


            ForEach((1...10).reversed(), id: \.self) {_ in
                Text(self.number2)

            }

            Text("\(numbers1)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            Text("\(numbers2)")
                .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()

            TextField("answer", text: self.$answer)
                .padding(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.all/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                .font(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.largeTitle/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
                //.keyboardType(.numberPad)



            Button(action:  {

                var addition: Int {

                    let addition = self.numbers1 + self.numbers2

                    return addition
                }

                print("submit button pressed")
                print(addition)
                if (self.answer == String(addition)) {
                    print("Answer is Correct!")

                }

                else {
                    print("Answer is Incorrect")

                }

                self.answer = ""


            }) {
                Text("Submit")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                .padding()
                .background(Color.red)

                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .cornerRadius(40)

            }
        //    .padding()
            .actionSheet(isPresented: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/ /*@PLACEHOLDER=Is Presented@*/.constant(false)/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/) {
                ActionSheet(title: Text(/*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/ /*@PLACEHOLDER=Title@*/"Action Sheet"/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/))
            }


        }


        }

    }



struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

    ```
    enter code here
````

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is this:
declare

```
@State var numbers1 : Int = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].randomElement()!
@State var numbers2 : Int = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].randomElement()!
```

and

```
if (self.answer == String(addition)) {
    print("Answer is Correct!")
    self.numbers1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].randomElement()!
    self.numbers2 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10].randomElement()!
}
```

or some variation of this, like storing the array in a var.

Comment: Thanks alot! That fixed it, i'll definitely note this for future reference.

Comment: glad I could help. Please mark the answer as correct.